# ImageButton doesn't match dark mode

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, imagebutton

I have created a ImageButton in my XML activity but it doesn't match the dark mode. The color of the backgroung and the image is still the same than normal mode.
I'm using a shape for this ImageButton and for others Buttons, I don't have trouble with the Buttons.

Here my code :

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/actionButtonDescription"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

And here my shape "roundedbutton.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid
    android:color="@color/primaryColor"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="200dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="200dp"
    android:topRightRadius="200dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="200dp"/>
```

Do I need any to add some parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line in your `ImageButton` tag:

```
android:tint="#0000ffff"
```

Here the code `#0000ffff` is for transparent colour.